# How to extract the year of a DATE and insert it in a new column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in my table which contains DATEs and I need to keep only the YEAR (=> in a NUMBER or INT type)

My idea was to add a column and try something like this :

```
UPDATE myTable SET newColumn=(
select to_number(to_char(oldColumn.year, 'yyyy')) from myTable)
```

But I get this error :

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

Could you help?!?

Comment: UPDATE myTable SET newColumn=(extract(year from datecol));

Comment: Step back and first think, would such a design be of any use? It is a bad idea to do that. Storing only a portion of date would hardly be of any use. Also, you won't be able to do any date arithmatic on the column.

To fetch the year value Oracle provides the datetime format for display. For any date calculation based on year you just need to do: If you still want to do it, the use `VIRTUAL COLUMN`.

Comment: Maybe oldcolumn is to be dropped when the year copying is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your query to:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET newColumn=to_number(to_char(oldColumn.year, 'yyyy'))
```

This `SELECT` statement will return all of the rows in the table, from column `oldColumn.year`, which generates your "single-row subquery returns **more than one row**" error.

`(select to_number(to_char(oldColumn.year, 'yyyy')) from myTable)`

Comment: It would be a bad idea to store computed values.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I never said it's a good idea, but in some scenarios it might be useful. Without knowing the actual use cases he is considering and/or the actual and intended end result we can't say for sure.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu The only case I came so far was while creating dashboards in OBIEE. We needed a computed value from table.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I wouldn't limit myself to my personal knowledge or experience regarding using computed columns when afirming that this is a bad idea. Maybe the OP can provide actual good reasons for why he would need a computed column. Maybe he will never need the rest of the date or maybe that's what he thinks now. Like I said, without knowing the actual intended result we cannot say for sure that it's a good or bad idea. Nevertheless, the question did not ask for an opinion on his design but for a solution to his query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`EXTRACT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) function:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET    newColumn = EXTRACT( YEAR FROM oldColumn.year )
```

Comment: Standard SQL plus much cleaner than the Oracle version :-)

Comment: @dnoeth - unfortunately, it doesn't work in SQL Server (or some earlier versions of DB2, I think).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: The OP asked for an Oracle solution, in SQL Server both `EXTRACT` and `TO_CHAR`/`TO_NUMBER` will fail...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse which is a problem in  a question tagged as ORACLE... why?

Comment: @xQbert - It's not, in itself.  Just another part of the standard somebody isn't implementing.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into table_name (v_date)
values ((select extract (year from current_date())));
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to do that. Storing only a portion of date would hardly be of any use. Also, you won't be able to do any date arithmatic on the column.

To fetch the year value Oracle provides the datetime format for display. For any date calculation based on year you just need to do:

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_column)
```

If you still want to change the design and store only the date part, then instead of creating a static column, use a **VIRTUAL COLUMN**.

For example,

```
dt_yyyy NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_column)) VIRTUAL
```

Or,

```
dt_yyyy NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_number(to_char(date_column, 'YYYY'))) VIRTUAL
```

**NOTE** : Virtual columns were introduced from 11g.

Comment: My problem was that I only need the year part of DATE and had to make an Extract() in each query which is not convenient...

I didn't know the existence of virtual columns, I will try this !

Comment: Although this is more convenient than doing Extract in queries, I think this is still a lost of time when computing a query, isn't it ?

Comment: @Piloumpicou `Virtual column` is the best method when you have a business need to store **computed values**. It is virtual, so it doesn't occupy any space. All it does is computed when the query is executed. I suggest, you should use a virtual column and do not alter the date column.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Basically a virtual column would be one that automatically executes an `EXTRACT()` for a pre-specified column, when you try to return data from it (virtual column), right?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Imagine it like a function, that's the reason when you create an index on virtual column, it is actually a function-based index. It computes value at runt time, and never stores it in database.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a perfect situation in which to use a virtual column if you are on at least 11g.  Consider this create table statement for my test table, where v_year is the virtual column:

```
CREATE TABLE X_TEST
(
  COL2       LONG,
  COL3       VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  COL4       VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  COL5       VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  COL6_DATE  DATE,
  V_YEAR     NUMBER Generated Always as (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "COL6_DATE"))
);
```

Now, just insert the date and Bam! the year is in there automagically! No special updating needed.

```
SQL> insert into X_TEST (col6_date) values (sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> select col6_date, v_year from X_TEST;

COL6_DATE     V_YEAR
--------- ----------
22-MAY-15       2015

SQL>
```

Some more info and examples: http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php